# Agiletoolkit: Or'ing ands

Tags: atk4

I have a query that gives me a number of pairs of context_id and class_id. I want one of those to be met by another query. So I need to do where (co1 and cl1) or (co2 and cl2) or...

This one gives me a series of and's:

```
foreach($tscarr as $tsc)
{
  $grid->dq->where('context_id',$tsc['context_id'])->where('class_id',$tsc['class_id']);
}
```

I know from this page: http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/dsql/where that I should be able to do or. But I get an error when trying to use or in this way:

```
$grid->dq->where($grid->dq->or()->where($grid->dq->where('context_id',$tsc['context_id'])->where('class_id',$tsc['class_id'])));
```

Hope you have a good idea how to solve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$dsql->orExpr()` method.

There are multiple examples in Stackoverflow like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/17958175/1466341 and also in ATK4 Google groups here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/agile-toolkit-devel just search for *orExpr*.

I guess in your case something like this should work (untested):

```
$q = $grid->dq;
$or = $q->orExpr();

foreach($tscarr as $tsc)
{
    $or->where(
        $q->andExpr()
            ->where('context_id', $tsc['context_id'])
            ->where('class_id',   $tsc['class_id'])
    );
}
$q->where($or);
```

Comment: more examples and info about `orExpr()` can be found here: https://github.com/atk4/docs/blob/master/web_development_with_agile_toolkit/chapter3/section3.md

Comment: This worked just perfectly! Thanks! It also taught me a lot about how objects work... So thanks again ;-)